# In ASP.NET MVC 4 how to create a custom html element

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

What do you do when you need a custom html element, like a button, listbox, radio button choice ?

[image]

## 1

As you can see, there is 4 choices of Layout in my example. If I used normal html element, I would replace the Web 2,Classic,Porte-Folio,Blog(Buttons) by a radio button.

## 2

In my example, there is "Social Network Link" Choice. The user can select as many social network as they wants. In Normal Html element, I would use a Listbox that give me the opportunity to select many option as I wants.

Here is my entity Framework Entities for this example

**Layout**
Id
LayoutName

**SocialNetwork**
Id
NetworkName
IconPath

**WebSite**
Id
LayoutID (FK With Layout) a website can Have only one layout chosen

**WebSiteNetwork** ( A Website can contain many network social link)
WebSiteID (FK With WebSite)
NetworkID (FK With Network)

Comment: i cant really understand what you are asking ...

Comment: Ok let me try to clarify my question. As you can see in my example, there are a section called (Select Your Layout) . In this section, I have 4 choices(Web2,Classic etc..). Instead of using a Radio button foreach choice, I'm using a custom Button composed with(<div class='MyButton'>Web 2</div>). When I Click Save, there is no way to know witch choice the user has selected because this is not a standart Html Element like a (hidden field, textbox, listbox) .

Comment: sry for my english, I Try to improve it :P

Comment: i tried to answer your question, hope that will help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your comment you can use the good old hidden input element like

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="userSel"/>
```

attach a click event handler with the custom button

```
 $(".MyButton").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#userSel").val($(this).text());
    })
```

;

you can attach the hidden input to a form and on user selection of `Blog` the hidden input will hold the value `Blog` on the server side you can look for the hidden field value

HTH

Comment: thanks , I Understand that I Need javascript to perform my needs.